# List of authors to the right, as a signature

Tags: horizontal-alignment, thesis

I am currently making the last adjustments to my groups BSc thesis and I am writing the acknowledgement. Currently it looks like:

```
Title
A lot of text.
                                             Name Family name, City, Month Year
Name2 Family name2
Name3 Family name3
...
```

But I would like it to be:

```
Title
A lot of text.
                                             Name Family name, City, Month Year
                                             Name2 Family name2
                                             Name3 Family name3
                                             ...
```

I.e, for the signature to be left aligned, but starting as many characters from the right edge as needed by the longest line in the block.

How is the achieved in the best way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `\pbox` with the `\textwidth` option from the `pbox` package and right-align that with an `\hfill` like this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pbox}

\begin{document}

Title

A lot of text.

\hfill\pbox{\textwidth}{
  Name Family name, City, Month Year\\
  Name2 Family name2\\
  Name3 Family name3
}

\end{document}
```

The `\textwidth` option makes sure that the`\pbox` is precisely as wide as the text containing it and then the `\hfill` shifts that as far to the right as possible. Note that you have to put line breaks between the names, otherwise they would end up on a single line.

This produces the following output:

[image]

Comment: With no package: `\hspace*{\fill}\begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}} a\\b\\c\end{tabular}`

Comment: Excellent answers. Thank you a lot, both of you.